# Como criar um novo submodulo zerado no git?

Tags: git

Qual a forma mais prática de criar um submódulo novo e vazio no git? Sempre que eu preciso estou tendo que criar fora para depois fazer o checkout com um url. Tem alguma forma mais direta com um ou poucos comandos, deixando o repositório já como submódulo e inicializado? sem remote mesmo? (eu adiciono depois pela IDE quando for subir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem algumas formas diferentes de lidar com submódulos em git. Não entendi muito bem o que você está querendo fazer, mas vê se é algumas dessas opções:

**Criar um submódulo especificando uma determinada branch em um repositório remoto**

```
git submodule add -b <branch> [URL to Git repo]  
git submodule init

Onde <branch> é a branch para onde você quer commitar o submodulo e a
[URL] é o caminho do repositório remoto.
```

**Criar um submódulo a partir de uma pasta de um repositório**

```
git init .
mkdir submodule
cd submodule
git init .
cd ..
git submodule add ./submodule submodule
```

Escrevi de forma "mais verbosa" para ajudar a entender o que acontece. Você pode adicionar uma pasta como submódulo local e posteriormente fazer um push para o remoto.