# Projeto python no github com submodulo

Tags: python, github

Tenho um projeto em python e quero incluir um submodulo (que é outro repo do github) no mesmo diretório, e quero que ele seja instalado de forma automática durante a instalação do modulo principal.

Isso é possível, se sim, como pode ser feito?

Modulo: https://github.com/luizoti/xkeysnail
Submodulo: https://github.com/gvalkov/python-evdev

UPDATE:
Sim, pesquisei sobre o assunto e como deve ser meio claro, é relacionado a python e não encontrei nada que sanasse a duvida.

Mas tudo bem, vamos imaginar que não seja um repositório no GIT, (nem o modulo e nem o submodulo), alguém pode me ajudar com essa duvida ou vão apenas apertar o seta para baixo?

Comment: Relacionado: [Como criar um novo submodulo zerado no git?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/440782/3774)

Comment: Relacionado: [Para que serve um submodule no git?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111313/3774)

Comment: Tem relação, mas em falando do python, como ele entende o submódulo e faz a instalação? ou é só o caso de colocar o submódulo em algum diretório que ele vai compreender?

Vlw.

Comment: Então é uma regra "Só não não cumprimente ou agradeça nas perguntas(e respostas)"?

Comment: Bom, eu havia deletado até pq era bobagem dar continuidade, mas ok, sua resposta sobre a regra apenas confirmou oque eu já tinha em mente, é uma regra bem boba, uma coisa são perguntas/respostas técnicas, outra é precisar de uma regra pra moderar comprimentos.

Mas ok, vida que segue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apenas pra manter um ciclo positivo de quem sabe mais ajuda quem sabe menos, segue a solução, espero que seja útil pra alguém.

No exemplo abaixo segue o `setup.py`, em primeiro adicionei o argumento `dependency_links` e nele o link do repositório no github `"https://github.com/luizoti/evdev/tarball/master#egg=evdev-1.4.1"` com a versão do pacote.

O teste foi feito no python 3.8.

Em seguida em `install_requires`, adicionei o nome do pacote "evdev==1.4.1" apontando para a versão dele.

Com esse modelo o pacote evdev é instalado ignorando o pacote existente via pip, no meu caso a necessidade veio por precisar instalar um fork modificado.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup

__doc__ = None
__name__ = None
__version__ = None
__description__ = None

exec(open("xkeysnail/info.py").read())

setup(
    name=__name__,
    version=__version__,  # pylint: disable=undefined-variable
    author="Masafumi Oyamada",
    url="https://github.com/mooz/xkeysnail",
    description=__description__,  # pylint: disable=undefined-variable
    long_description=__doc__,
    packages=["xkeysnail"],
    scripts=["bin/xkeysnail"],
    license="GPL",
    dependency_links=[
        "https://github.com/luizoti/evdev/tarball/master#egg=evdev-1.4.1",
    ],
    install_requires=[
        "evdev==1.4.1",
        "python-xlib",
        "inotify_simple",
        "psutil"
    ],
)
```